# Is there a way to have a similar gtsummary table within a function

Tags: r, gtsummary

I am trying to create a table with gtsummay package inside a function. I find problem with value of **N** not correct. Am not sure whether am missing something. I would like just to have the value of **N** after filtering. I have introduced missing values in the grade variable for demonstration purposes.

```
library(gtsummary)
library(dplyr)
trialmiss <- trial %>% mutate(grade = factor(ifelse(age<10, NA, as.character(grade))))

# My function
mytable <- function(variable){
  trialmiss %>%
    select(variable) %>%
    filter(!is.na(variable)) %>%
    tbl_summary()
}

mytable("grade")

# Desired Output

trialmiss %>%
  filter(!is.na(grade)) %>%
  select(grade) %>% tbl_summary()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `.data` pronoun.

```
mytable <- function(variable){
  trialmiss %>%
    select(variable) %>%
    filter(!is.na(.data[[variable]])) %>%
    tbl_summary()
}

mytable("grade")
```

[image]

You may also use include `sym` (`filter(!is.na(!!sym(variable)))`) Or `get` for the same (`filter(!is.na(get(variable)))`).

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I wanted